# Filtering large files from Dropbox

Tags: dropbox

My fiancee would like to use Dropbox, but she has this issue with it: She would like to exclude some files from being stored on dropbox, because they are too large.

She would like to store a unified folder structure of her work, but some of her files are too big. She wouldn't like to store them separately, but doesn't mind if they're not uploaded to dropbox. In fact, she prefers that they won't be uploaded so they don't clog up her space.

How would you solve this issue? Windows shortcuts?

Comment: This same problem exists for the iPad client. Not a very useful application without this feature.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this at the time. Using Windows shortcuts is one possibility to make it as though the files are located in the same folders, however, it seems like it would get a bit complicated if there are a lot of folders.

There is a [feature request](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/1876/exclude-files-above-max-size-limit) for this exact issue, which you can vote on.

Other features you may want to look for is the [ability to watch any folder](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/11/watch-any-folder), which you might be able to use in conjunction with your file system to create a limited set of folders to sync. Another one that might help is [excluding certain file extensions](https://www.dropbox.com/votebox/2385/option-to-exclude-by-file-extension), this would help if all the large files are of the same type (e.g. .exe, .avi, etc.).

Answer (score 2):

You could use junctions from sysinternals. Its like hard links for windows.

It works great for me. Just make a junction from a source folder inside dropbox to a target folder that is outside of dropbox. Despite what the dropbox support team says this method works. I got it going on a windows server right now.

mkdir Dropbox\folder-inside-dropbox

junction.exe Dropbox\folder-inside-dropbox\ C:\whatever\target-folder\you\want...\

http://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=60991&replies=3

This will only partially work. You must restart dropbox to see new files.

Comment: FYI, Of note, Windows 7 and 8 have a built-in utility "mklink" which can create directory junctions.